# how to display total records in Postgresql DB based on attribute

Tags: html, css, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display a numerical value for total number of Active and Pending calls. Currently i have these broken out into two panels and would like to include a visible number to show how many of each type are in que.

I have searched this out but its all very convoluted and makes not much sense.

the column name is "status" and in the call create page the have the option to select "assigned" and "pending"

below is my controller for reference.

Calls Controller:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
    @active_calls = Call.where(status: 'active')
    @pending_calls = Call.where(status: 'pending')
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id)
    end
end
```

the Postgresql side of things is my weakness and i am currently working to strengthen this.

Thanks in advance for you assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where (which controller action) you are looking to perform the counts.

**If it's in `index`:**

It seems like you already load the related records into memory with:

```
@active_calls = Call.where(status: 'active')
@pending_calls = Call.where(status: 'pending')
```

So you don't need to issue a new query, you can simply call Ruby's `length` method like this:

```
@active_calls.length
@pending_calls.length
```

By the way, I would probably avoid running three queries like you do at the moment and do something like this:

```
@calls = Call.all 
@active_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'active'}
@pending_calls = @calls.select{|x| x.status == 'pending'}
```

And use the `@active_calls.length` and `@pending_calls.length` as before. The reason is that every trip to the database comes with an overhead. It might not seem much, but these latencies add up and make your controller action slower. So generally you want to reduce the number of trips to the database as much as you can. The code above uses Ruby's `select` method to go over the array and pick the elements for which the block is evaluated as true; this happens in memory and does not require a trip to the database.

**If it's in a different controller action:**

Assuming that in that other controller action you do not load an array of `Call` Active Record objects, you probably want to issue `COUNT(*)` queries. These are generally faster than loading all the records and performing the count in memory (e.g. with `length`), because the database server simply needs to return you a number instead of all the records data, and you also save the overhead of building Active Record objects.

The way to do this with Active Record is simply:

```
Call.where(status: 'active').count
Call.where(status: 'pending').count
```

If you want want to do one `COUNT` query with a `GROUP BY` instead of two separate queries (good idea, as it saves an extra trip to the database), you could do this:

```
Call.group(:status).count
```

This would result in a hash such as `{'active' => 150, 'pending' => 120}` which you can use in your view.